# Can I or can't I develop on a jailbreak iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Does any one have a definitive answer?

I am reading so many answers that tell you both thing, one tells you that it is not a problem at all and the other one is very definite NO...Is there any developer over here that has a jailbreaked iPhone that is using it to test the application in development?

From what I heard from friends, Not over the web, Apple don't allow that and is checking for that, but over the web I've read that it is not a problem....

I will eventually remove the  jailbreak that was installed on my lovely iPhone, but I want to know if to do it now or can I wait with that because I want the person that installed it to remove it and give me the iPhone I asked for....never mind, if I can wait, I prefer to do it this way (might take weeks of month as we do not leave in the same place) but if I have to, I will do it by myself and that's all..

Comment: You will get no definitive answer because this depends on how much you modify/customize the OS, and you can modify a rooted OS enough to break anything and everything, or so little that nothing seems different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jailbreak does not affect the functionality of the phone except to allow MORE things to run on it, so there's no reason to think it won't work for development.

Comment: 10x, So i can test on it for now? no problems? I don't like that, I want it the way apple intended it to be. But for now, untill i get hold of the place and get there, and kick some ass, I can work and test on it with no problems at all?

Comment: I honestly don't see why not. Functionally speaking, the phone is the same.

Comment: I guess that just becouse i don't like using somg the wrong way...Apple build it and they want it to be jailbreak free. But that's stupid me... :-)

Comment: Hardly. While Apple may have good reasons for disallowing access to the OS, it doesn't make you stupid.

Comment: I didn't mean that i am stupid becouse of that, that i was saying is that "stupid me" for not wanting like every one else to jailbreak my iphone. becouse i belive, as you said, that apple have good reasons for disallowing access. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've used my former [lost](http://cauecmrego.blogspot.com/2011/04/iphones-perdidos-ou-roubados.html) jailbroken iPhone to develop, yes. But you'll need more than jailbreaking, though, granted, **jailbreak is a must** (except in very specific cases):

- Actually the only very rare specific exception I know of is the [Unity 3D's amazing **Remote**](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/unity-extensions/unity-remote) - but that does (currently) limit phone features that can be tested. No gyroscope for instance.
- The regular way is [hacking Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498). Of course the limitation here is deploying: only with USB.
- Another way could be something like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) - while I'm not sure this can be done without a proper developer license, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a way to do it [Over the Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415161/over-the-air-deployment-of-iphone-app).